# SQL Server Transaction syntax

Tags: sql-server

```
-- 1    
DELETE QDEB 
FROM QuoteDetailExtensionBase QDEB 
LEFT JOIN QuoteDetailBase QDB
ON QDEB.QuoteDetailId = QDB.QuoteDetailId
WHERE QDB.DeletionStateCode = 2

-- 2
DELETE FROM QuoteDetailBase WHERE DeletionStateCode = 2
```

How do I stop the second deletion happening if there was any problem with the first?

I know I need a transaction but what is the correct syntax?

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
...
END
COMMIT
```

Is that correct?

Thanks

Comment: http://rusanu.com/2010/11/22/try-catch-throw-exception-handling-in-t-sql/

Answer (score 0):

```
begin try
begin tran
--two delete statements
commit
end try
begin catch
rollback tran
select error_message()
end catch
```

You could also use, <kbd>SET XACT_ABORT</kbd> ,this roll backs entire batch in case of any error..so your delete statements can go like this and they will both be rolled back in case of any error

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
delete statement1;
delete statement2 ;
go
```